# First UITableViewCell not calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

The weirdest thing is happening when I select a `UITableViewCell`.

If I select the first one it doesn't do anything, but when I select the second one, It does call the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, but with the values of the first one.

I should mention that I'm using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` inside of it. I should also mention that I just started using `IOS 7`.

Here is my code.

ChannelsPopoverViewController.h

```
@interface ChannelsPopoverViewController :UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *channelsTableView;

@end
```

ChannelsPopoverViewController.m

```
@implementation ChannelsPopoverViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.channelsTableView.delegate=self;
    self.channelsTableView.dataSource=self;
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"new account cell"];
    UIImageView *channelImage=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *cellLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        channelImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"App-dropbox-icon.png"];
        cellLabel.text=@"add dropbox";
    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        channelImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Google-Drive-icon.png"];
        cellLabel.text=@"add google drive";
    }



    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *cellLabel=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    if ([cellLabel.text isEqual:@"add dropbox"]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: How do you know is not loaded. Try add NSLog(@"Row: %d", indexPath.row); to didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:. Replace isEqual: to isEqualToString.

Comment: You are using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath either not didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath, not didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Yeah, has happened to me also.

Answer (score 2):

**Fist of all**:

`[cellLabel.text isEqual:@"add dropbox"]`

should really be

`[cellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"add dropbox"]`

**Second of all**:

You should really make use of `indexPath` in **`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`** method.

*Example*:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason that didSeletRowAtIndexPath() doesn't get called is having a UITapGestureRecognizer on your viewcontroller with 'Cancels touches in view' set to 'YES'.

The correct and only sensible fix is to set 'Cancels touches in view' to 'NO'. Then your table row selection should work nicely.

Obviously this has some implications in your gesture handlers - you may need to add some code to your gesture handler to stop some touches going on to your views i.e.

```
- (IBAction)onTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (sender.view == someOldViewThatINeedToDealWith) {
        sender.cancelsTouchesInView = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh god. I do have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on my `UITableViewController`'s table view so that the keyboard is dismissed when the user taps outside of the cells. Damn Apple, how am I supposed to just know this? Thanks for the help.